# Django form doesn't validate

Tags: django, validation, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to an Amazon S3 bucket using Django.
I've created an html form and am passing the POST data to a function based view. I've looked around and tried numerous things but I can't seem to get it to validate.

(In case it's relevant: I've already configured the S3 setup in settings and it seems to work just fine for handling static files)

Errors when printing to console:

```
ValueError: The Document could not be created because the data didn't validate.

<ul class="errorlist"><li>upload<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required</li></ul></li></ul>
```

**EDIT**:
It seems that the validation will only work if I set the input `name="upload"` EVEN when I set `fields = "__all__"` in the model form. This breaks my requirement of having a variable number of inputs for my form.

**Model**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from messaging_platform.storage_backends import PrivateMediaStorage


class Document(models.Model):
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    upload = models.FileField()


class PrivateDocument(models.Model):
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    upload = models.FileField(storage=PrivateMediaStorage())
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='documents', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**ModelForm**

```
from django import forms
from apps.core.models.document import Document


class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('upload',)
```

**View**

```
def edit(request, message_id=None):
    user_obj = get_login_user_objects(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # tried all of these three variants
        form = DocumentForm(request.FILES['content_url_0'])
        form = DocumentForm(request.FILES)
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

**Template**

```
{% for img_upload in img_upload_list %}
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control border-input input-child" placeholder="https://example.com/original.jpg" name="content_url_{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ img_upload.payload }}" required>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your form's field named `upload` django expecting same name in posted data. So you should rename field in your tamplate `name=upload`:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control border-input input-child" placeholder="https://example.com/original.jpg" name="upload" value="{{ img_upload.payload }}" required>
```

After this you'll be able to validate form with simple:

```
form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

If you want to upload multiple images at the same time, you can use [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/) or follow [this method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files) descibed in the docs.

Comment: doh, that I didn't notice that... On a side note would there be a way to process dynamic fields without using FormSets? The form is currently rather complex and is manipulated through Javascript.

Comment: @MSB I've added another link to my answer. Try to use field's `multiple` attribute.

Comment: it seems that even when I use ```fields = '__all__'``` it stil doesn't validate

Comment: @MSB hm.. did you change `name="upload"` in your html?

Comment: even when I do the model still will not validate. Is there any additional info I could provide?

Comment: @MSB do you set form's `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute? Check example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173531/discussion-between-msb-and-neverwalkaloner).